# Perl: create a string without copying

Tags: perl, replace, substring

In Perl 5.20 I need to run a regular expression on a substring without copying it into a new string. So some equivalent to `$str[$to]` in the C language.

The reason is that it is executed in a loop and if it each time copies the string so the resulting code is `O(n^2)` while what without the copying it would be just `O(n)`. So with an input of 2MB string it is unusable.

Alternatively, I will welcome a suggestion on how to rewrite the code: I need to do a search and replace using a lookup table.

Example input

```
$str: "abcde"
$tbl: {ab=>"xy", bc=>"rq", e=>"a"}
$reg: qr/ab|bc|e/
expected output: xycda
```

This is my current code that runs fine for short strings, but it does not finish for large ones:

```
#translate $str: if $reg match found, replace the match with a value in $tbl hash that corresponds to the match
sub internalEncode {
    my ($str, $tbl, $reg) = @_;
    my $res="";
    my $prevTo = 0;
    my $to = 0;
    #the substr($str,$to) makes it slow; in C with 0 terminated strings
    #I would need to write here something like: $str[$to]
    while (substr($str,$to) =~ $reg) {
        my $match = $&;
        my $from = $prevTo + $-[0];
        $to = $prevTo + $+[0];
        $res .= substr($str,$prevTo,$from - $prevTo);
        $res .= $tbl->{quotemeta $match};
        $prevTo = $to;
    }
    $res .= substr($str,$prevTo);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: "*I will welcome a suggestion on how to rewrite the code*" ... Sure, but what the heck are you trying to do? Explain with sample data.

Comment: It's almost certainly a lot easier if you're using some of perl's build in elements - a search and replace using a lookup table is really easy using a hash. But without some example input/output we can't even begin to start.

Comment: I added the example. I use Perl 5.20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl is not C. And, using regular expressions is another step beyond that. So, I am going to break down steps required to implement something that might seem trivial once you have seen it, but might be hard to come up with if you are still in the C mindset.

Your example is:

```
$str: "abcde"
$tbl: {ab=>"xy", bc=>"rq", e=>"a"}
$reg: qr/ab|bc|e/
expected output: xycda
```

Let's think about how to implement this just for this particular case.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcde';
my $tbl = { ab => "xy", bc => "rq", e => "a"};
my $pat = qr{ ( ab | bc | e ) }x;

$str =~ s/$pat/$tbl->{$1}/g;

print "$str\n";
```

That is, we have three possible substrings we want to match against. When a match is found, we want to capture it, and replace it with the corresponding string in the lookup table.

I constructed the pattern separately, because I want to avoid manually typing it when I can actually derive it from the keys of the lookup table:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcde';
my $tbl = { ab => "xy", bc => "rq", e => "a"};
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta($_), sort keys %$tbl;

$str =~ s/($pat)/$tbl->{$1}/g;

print "$str\n";
```

Comment: This is ikegami's answer _plus_ an explanation. I like that.

Comment: Does not work: `Use of uninitialized value $1 in hash element at .\/Encode/fmx3.pm line 153, <$in> line 1.` the line 153 contains `my $res = $str =~ s/$reg/$tbl->{$1}/gr;` The $1 does not refer to a match but to a variable that is expected to be initialized before this line.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot $reg in (), now `s/($reg)/...` looks better

Comment: ikegami, Sinan Ünür: Thanks a lot guys. I am actually sorry that there is no solution for the no copying of the string (and terrified, I realized that even in Java 7+ the String.substring method is now O(n) instead of O(1) in the past...), but I definitely improved my Perl knowledge here.

Answer (score 5):

```
my $str = "abcde";
my $tbl = {ab=>"xy", bc=>"rq", e=>"a"};
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %$tbl;
$re = qr/($re)/;

$str =~ s/$re/$tbl->{$1}/g;
say $str;  # xycda
```

---

If you don't want to change the original:

```
my $res = $str =~ s/$re/$tbl->{$1}/rg;     # 5.14+
```

or

```
( my $res = $str ) =~ s/$re/$tbl->{$1}/g;
```

Comment: Wow, this looks promising I didn't hope that such construct would be possible. I will have time to try it only tomorrow.

Comment: Perl is a much higher level language than C, so you can do all sorts of nice things like that.

Comment: @Sobrique, I would expect C regex libraries to provide exactly the same functionally

Comment: Yes, I reckon. But with fewer `$` signs and more function calls. ;-)

Comment: The same as I commented for Sinan's answer: Does not work: `Use of uninitialized value $1 in hash element at .\/Encode/fmx3.pm line 153, <$in> line 1.` the line 153 contains `my $res = $str =~ s/$reg/$tbl->{$1}/gr;` The $1 does not refer to a match but to a variable that is expected to be initialized before this line.

Comment: apparently there should be `s/($re)/$tbl->{$1}/g`

Comment: No. I already included the capture in `$re`. My program works as-is. (Well, you need to add `use strict; use warnings; use feature qw( say );`, but that's it.) Whatever you ran is different than what I posted.